# How can I make an HTML element clickable only at certain screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to convert an old, custom-built web site to be responsive. I've got the main bulk of the CSS work done and can get the sizings and positioning that I want for the most part. There's one last piece that's giving me grief.

I have a series of news articles displayed on the page. When I go to mobile phone-size displays, I really want those headings to become "clickable" so that I can use them to show/hide the detail of the article. But I don't want those headings to be clickable at larger screen sizes.

The basic layout of each article is...

```
<article id="article-001">
    <div class="newsArticleTitle">Title goes here</div>
    <div class="newsArticleTeaser">
        <p>
            Teaser paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div class="newsArticleContent">
        <p>
            Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>
            Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

The relevant CSS that controls the display of those articles as the screen size reduces are...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .newsArticleTeaser {
        display: none;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 319px) {
    .newsArticleContent {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

...so that at the narrowest screen sizes, only the article title is visible. I then need/want that article title (the div with `class="newsArticleTitle"`) to then become a clickable item such that the visibility of the teaser and content will be toggled.

Is there a sane way to make that happen? My fallback method will probably be to duplicate the heading element - once with an `<a>` tag wrapping it, once without - and toggle the visibility of those two with CSS. That feels wrong though.

Has anyone solved this more elegantly or got any suggestions for a better way of designing this?

Comment: Post some code so we have an idea of your layout etc.

Comment: You could use javascript and a click event to return false on the link when a certain screen size is met. Needs code to be more specific

Comment: Could you please post your code fiddle.

Comment: You can have one clickable element and one non-clickable, and using *media queries* can hide and show based on the current screen size.

Comment: @Ankit - that's the fallback that I've mentioned in the original question. It feels wrong though. There shouldn't be a need to include extra elements just for this purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the css property `pointer-events: none` in combination with media queries:

```
.elementToClickInMobile {
    pointer-events: none;
    @media all and (max-width: 460px) {
        pointer-events: all
    }
}
```

this would prevent any click event in larger screens than `460px`

**EDIT//**
as correctly suggested this works >IE10

fallback for older (outdated) browser you could use

```
$("elementToClick").click(function(e){
    var outerWidth = window.outerWidth
    if (outerWidth > 480) {
        e.preventDefault(); //for browsers
        e.returnValue = false; //for IE
        return false
    }
});
```

JS not tested, so feel free to comment further suggestions!

**EDIT2//** found a neat fallback for IE7+ pointer events including a `preventClick()` method! https://github.com/vistaprint/PointyJS

Answer (score 3):

If supporting older versions (<11) of Internet Explorer is not an issue for you, then you could do this with CSS alone, using the `pointer-events` property and a media query:

```
@media all and (min-width:600px){
    h1{
        pointer-events:none;
    }
}
```

- [More information on `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)
- [Browser support for `pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)
- [More information on media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

If you like to do this via script, you could check `window.innerWidth`;

```
onclick = function() {
...
if(checkScreenSize()) {
    alert("Your screen is small!");
    ....
}
...
}

function checkScreenSize(){
    return window.innerWidth < 300; //The screen size you would like to enable the click;
}
```

Refer [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u3wL8dwd/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're after? This uses JQuery to toggle the relevant .newsArticleContent to be shown on a click of the title. You can test on the CSS like this since the .newsArticleContent is set to display:none at the appropriate screen size. You could look into the .toggle() function to have the title clicked a second time to re-hide the content.

```
    if ($(".newsArticleContent").css("display") == "none") {
        $(".newsArticleTitle").bind("click", function(){
            $(this).siblings(".newsArticleContent").show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not really - I know how to toggle an element's visibility but I only want the title to be an active element for certain screen sizes. Your suggestion would mean clicking on the title at large sizes would hide the article (and then allow the user to show it again, admittedly, with a second click). The question is about how to alter the role of the title, not the action to take after a click.

Comment: If I understood your CSS correctly, you only set the .newsArticleContent to be display:none at the lowest screen size you have set (less than 319px). The above code would only run when that CSS was active, meaning the title would only be clickable when the content was hidden, at the lower screen size?

Comment: OK - but I would need to run that code on ready() and also on every resize. And it brings with it a dependency on JQuery.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){checkSize();$(window).resize(checkSize);});` Place that code in a function called "checkSize". It does bring about the dependency yes, but is also probably one of the easier ways to go about doing this ^^ best of luck my friend whatever option you take! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the following works and is the best way to do it if you don't have to consider IE10.

```
.elementToClickInMobile {
    pointer-events: none;
    @media all and (max-width: 460px) {
        pointer-events: all
    }
}
```

You can also check the size of the viewport using window.innerWidth. Be careful not to use window.outerwidth because it gets the width of the outside of the browser window. It represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.